# Product page with mod_rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working in a catalog store, so far i solved the url rewrite for the main page of the store (**store.php**) and the categories pages (**category.php**), this is what i got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category-store\.php\?catid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ category.php?catid=$1 [QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So the store page is

www.example.com/store

And a category page is

www.example.com/store/furniture

I try to break the products page i want it turn this:
www.example.com/product.php?id=1
into 
www.example.com/store/wood-chair-1

This is what i got that doesn't work...

```
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2 [QSA]
```

(.*) as product title - ([0-9]+) as product id

This is link example in php:

```
<a href="store/' . $row['prod_title'] .'-' . $row['id'] . '">'. $row['prod_title'] . '</a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to redirect where it breaks?

Comment: Something like www.example.com/product.php?id=4 cannot be turned into www.example.com/store/wood-chair-1 using regular expressions, if that is what you were expecting. This would involve finding out what is actually the product with id 4, which is not the job of regex.

Comment: Apart from ...-1 not being id=4, but id=1, what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, updated. My problem is a 404.

Comment: You're better of going `/store/`, `/store/category/`, `/store/category/product-name-id/` which will be easier to route and avoid potential collisions. I think your main problem is putting these pretty URLs in your content to begin with, it's a lot easier than redirecting every URL to a pretty version that has to find out what category and product names to add when the page that produced the link would already have that information.